# In Google Adwords, what is 'AR$'?

Tags: google-adwords

I'm asking this in the Web Applications section, not the Language section because it's specific to Google Adwords:

In Google Adwords, what does the 'AR' of 'AR$' mean?

Answer (score 2):

Argentinian Peso

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argentine_Peso

Also see - [What is an AR$ ??](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/AdWords/thread?tid=18f2ddf3ee8156e2&hl=en)

Hope this helps.